# How to get timestamp of pushnotification in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, payload

I am trying to get pushnotification data. I am able to get title and body but i am also trying to get timestamp.

I am getting data like

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print full message.

        guard
            let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
            let body = alert["body"] as? String,
            let title = alert["title"] as? String
            else {
                // handle any error here
                return
            }

        print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")

        completionHandler()
    }
```

is there any way to get timestamp in pushnotification payload itself or via any other way?

Comment: what do you mean by time stamp of push notification? Time at which notification was sent or time at which your device received the notification? what emrcftci suggested will solve first question but if you need to address second one then you have to take different approach

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Thanks Sandeep. i am trying to get timestamp when user receive pushnotifiation. not sure if  emrcftci  way is possible for Firebase pushnotification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add custom `timestamp` data into your `Push Notification`'s payload.

Normally the payload looks like this;

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":{
            "title":"Hello",
            "body":"How are you?"
        },
        "badge":0,
        "sound":"default"
    }
}
```

---

If you want to add custom fields into the payload it should be look like ->

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":{
            "title":"Hello",
            "body":"How are you?"
        },
        "badge":0,
        "sound":"default"
    },
    "timestamp": "1590736069"
}
```

The custom fields are has to locate outside to `aps` object.

Please check this out -> [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1)

---

Then you need to parse it

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print full message.

    guard
        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary,
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
        let body = alert["body"] as? String,
        let title = alert["title"] as? String,
        let timestamp = userInfo["timestamp"] as? String
            else {
                // handle any error here
                return
            }

    print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")
    print("Timestamp is: \(timestamp)")
    completionHandler()
}
```

**Note:** Don't need to use `AnyHashable` to use string as a key. Use like `userInfo["aps"]`

---

**Getting current date's timestamp**

If you need to know notification received date you can simply get current `Date`'s timestamp value like this ->

```swift
// Declare this in `didReceive` method and now you know the timestamp of notification received date
let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: Thanks for solution.. but i am using Firebase pushnotification..is this possible to add / get timestamp from firebase pushnotificartion

Comment: @user7423463 I've updated my answer. As I understand you need to know timestamp value of notification received date. And you can do this without parsing `payload`'s values. I hope it is what you need.